# Rock Paper Scissors Always Lets Me Win

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a new programmer and am trying to familiarize myself with if else statements by creating a rock paper scissors game. My problem is that the code always lets me win. In addition, my while loop won't actually loop so any help with this stuff would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

The code:

```
from random import randint

t = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

computer = t[randint(0, 2)]

player = False

while player == False:
    player = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors: ").lower()
    if player == computer:
        print("Computer:" + player.capitalize())
        print("Tie!")
    elif player == "rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("Computer: Paper")
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("Computer: Scissors")
            print("You Win!")
    elif player == "paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("Computer: Scissors")
            print("You Lose!")
        else:
            print("Computer: Rock")
            print("You win")
    elif player == "scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("Computer: Rock")
            print("You lose!")
        else:
            print("Computer: Paper")
            print("You Win!")
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Try again!")

player = False
computer = t[randint(0, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game doesn't repeat because your condition `player == False` is never true after the player has made a choice. It always contains the player's last choice, which isn't `False`.

Instead of using that `while` condition, allow the user to enter something like `quit`. Then check for that before running the rest of the code, and break out of the loop.

You can use `random.choice()` to select an item from a list, instead of `randint()`.

The computer's choice needs to be in the loop. Otherwise, the player can always win because the computer's choice never changes.

```
from random import choice

t = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

while True:
    player = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors, or quit: ").lower()
    if player == 'quit':
        break
    computer = choice(t)
    if player == computer:
        print("Computer:" + player.capitalize())
        print("Tie!")
    elif player == "rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("Computer: Paper")
            print("You lose")
        else:
            print("Computer: Scissors")
            print("You Win!")
    elif player == "paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("Computer: Scissors")
            print("You Lose!")
        else:
            print("Computer: Rock")
            print("You win")
    elif player == "scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("Computer: Rock")
            print("You lose!")
        else:
            print("Computer: Paper")
            print("You Win!")
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Try again!")
```

Comment: And in his program, if the loop did repeat, the player would always be able to win because they know the computer's choice from the first play.

Comment: I suspect he just didn't play enough times to lose.